# Eliminar de Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<tbody class="">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="bntElim" runat="server"  CssClass="borrar"  AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="bntElim_Click" CommandName="BtnBorrar" >
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="imgs/borrar.png" Style="border-width: 0px;" Height="25px" Width="25px" CssClass="borrar" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </td>

        <td class="col-md-1 ">
            <asp:TextBox  Text=' <%# DevolverCantidadNoParte(Eval("NoParte").ToString()) %>'  Parte='<%#Eval("NoParte") %>' Costo='<%#Eval("CostoMx") %>' runat="server" ID="txtcantidad" type="numeric" OnTextChanged="txtcantidad_TextChanged" Style="width: 30px; text-align: center;"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="Noparteescondido" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("NoParte") %>' />
        </td>

        <td class="col-md-1"><%#Eval("NoParte") %></td>

        <td class="col-md-4"><%#Eval("DescripcionParte") %></td>

        <td class="col-md-1" id="cantidad1"><%#Eval("Existencia") %> </td>

        <td class="col-md-1"><%#Eval("CostoMx") %></td>

        <td class="col-md-1">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsubtotal" Text='<%#Multiplicar(decimal.Parse(Eval("CostoMx" ).ToString()),DevolverCantidadNoParte(Eval("NoParte").ToString())) %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.borrar', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
</script>
```

-

```
protected void txtcantidad_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox txtcantidad = ((TextBox)sender);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtcantidad.Text) )
    {

        var listassub = (List<decimal>)Session["lblsubtotal"];
        string numparte = txtcantidad.Attributes["Parte"].ToString();
        decimal costonoparte = decimal.Parse(txtcantidad.Attributes["Costo"]);


        foreach (RepeaterItem r in rptDetalleprod.Items)
        {
            HiddenField hd = (HiddenField)r.FindControl("Noparteescondido");
            if (hd.Value == numparte)
            {
                decimal subtotal = decimal.Parse(txtcantidad.Text) * costonoparte;
                Label labelsubtotal = (Label)r.FindControl("lblsubtotal");
                labelsubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();

                listassub.Add(subtotal);
                List<string> listanoparte = (List<string>)Session["noparte"];
                var indice = listanoparte.IndexOf(numparte);
                List<int> listaenteros = (List<int>)Session["lstcantidad"];
                listaenteros.Insert(indice, int.Parse(txtcantidad.Text));
                listaenteros.RemoveAt(indice + 1);
                Session["lstcantidad"] = listaenteros;
                //break;
            }
            total = listassub.Sum();
            txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            txtnoparte.Focus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("La cantidad debe ser menor a Cero");
    }
}
```

Estoy usando este método para eliminar el `row` pero al momento de actualizar se vuelven a agregar los valores que se eliminaron, que puedo utilizar para que no se vuelva a agregar.

Comment: Como cargas los valores?

Comment: cada vez que escaneo un codigo de un producto se trae con un query de sql los valores, y en cada td agrege un eval,

Comment: Podrias agregar ese codigo?

Comment: la agrege arriba, no la pude acmodar

Comment: Quieres que al eliminarlos tambien se eliminen en la base de datos?

Comment: no, solo de la tabla

Comment: A que te refieres con actualizar, cuando recargas la pagina?

Comment: cuando en la tabla le doy un valor se recarga la informacion para darme un total en ese momento si elimine un valor de la tabla vuelve a aparecer.

Comment: Agrega tambien el codigo que te genera el total.

Comment: La variable `rptDetalleprod` es la que utilizas para cargar los valores?

Comment: si, esa uso para cargar la tabla

Comment: Ese es tu problema, no solo tienes que eliminar la fila de la tabla, sino que tambien tienes que eliminar el item de la variable `rptDetalleprod`.  Te recomiendo que uses `ajax`.

Comment: tendras un ejemplo?, o como quiera dejame buscar algo, gracias

Comment: Creo que tambien podrias hacerlo en el handler `bntElim_Click`.